# Issue in scraping data from a website using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape list of 41 items & their prices from a website. But my output csv is missing some 2-3 items which come at the end of the page. Reason for this being, some devices have their price mentioned in different class than rest of the devices. 
Recursion in my code is running for name and price together and for items where price is mentioned under different class, it is taking the price value from the next device. Hence, it is skipping last 2-3 items as prices for those devices already entered in recursion for previous devices.
Below is the referred code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListGridView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('AT&T_2012-12-28.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=True)
    prices = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "listGrid-price"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        if textcontent:            
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').replace('â„¢','').replace('Â®','').strip(),textcontent])
```

Price are usually mentioned under `listGrid-price` but for some 2-3 items which are outofstock at the moment price is under `listGrid-price-outOfStock` I need to include this also in my recursion so that right price comes before the item and loop runs for all the devices.

Please pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a comparator function, to make custom comparison and pass it to your `findAll()`.

So if you modify your line with `prices` assignment to:

```
prices = soup.findAll('div', class_=match_both)
```

and define the function as:

```
def match_both(arg):
    if arg == "listGrid-price" or arg == "listGrid-price-outOfStock":
        return True
    return False
```

(function can be made much more concise, verbosity here just to give you an idea of how it works)

it will thus compare to both and return a match in any of the cases.

More info can be found in [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class). (The has_six_characters variant)

Now, since you also asked how to exclude particular text.

`text` argument to `findAll()` can also have custom comparators.
So in this case, you don't want text saying `Write a review` to match and cause a shift in price vs text.

Hence your edited script to exclude review part:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def match_both(arg):
    if arg == "listGrid-price" or arg == "listGrid-price-outOfStock":
        return True
    return False

def not_review(arg):
    if not arg:
        return arg
    return "Write a review" not in arg

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListGridView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('AT&T_2012-12-28.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "clickStreamSingleItem"},text=not_review)
    prices = soup.findAll('div', class_=match_both)
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        if textcontent:
                spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').replace('â„¢','').replace('Â®','').strip(),textcontent])
```

Comment: Thanks! this works I think, but because of one more similar problem I am not able to get desired output.
Problem: All item names are under 'clickStreamSingleItem' class, now there is one more thing coming under this class which is "Write a Review" text. This again is creating problems in the recursion and causing mismatch between item names and prices. Please help me with this.

Comment: Same, write a custom comparator :)

Comment: How do I implement that in this problem? Class here are same but I need to ignore "Write a review" string when it is coming under a class, so that my csv is free of it.

Comment: Or, if "write a review" is the only thing, the easiest would be: add `            if "Write a review" not in item.string:` just after `if textcontent:`

Comment: But if I put ` if "Write a review" not in item.string:` just after `if textcontent` it will skip those prices also which are coming immediately after "write a review" as recursion is running for both items and prices together & Again some devices will be skipped

Comment: See edit :) Looks like this is what you want. Let me know if you need more explanation on how this works.

Comment: Can you go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068259/beautiful-soup-not-scraping-data-from-the-shtml-page and help me if you can.